# How can i log all dns request by powershell and task scheduler?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I want to log dns request history.
So i made up powershell script below.

```
$PROC_ID = Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=3006]" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty processid   
$TIMESTAMP = Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=3006]" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty timecreated     
$LOG_MSG = Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System/EventID=3006]" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty message  

$PROC_NAME = Get-Process -id $PROC_ID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty processname  
$TIMESTAMP_SPLIT = $TIMESTAMP -split " "       
$LOG_DATE = $TIMESTAMP_SPLIT[0]        
$LOG_TIME = $TIMESTAMP_SPLIT[1]       
$LOG_URL = $LOG_MSG -replace '^\S{2}\s([^,]+).+','$1'

$LOG = "$LOG_DATE`t$LOG_TIME`t$PROC_ID`t$PROC_NAME`t$LOG_URL"  
$LOG >> C:\dns.csv
```

And i made up task schedule that run script when occur 3006 event.

```
C:\>schtasks /query /tn dns_history /fo list /v

Folder:                                 \
HostName:                               LG
TaskName:                               \dns_history
Next Run Time:                          N/A
Status:                                 Ready
Logon Mode:                             Interactive/Background
Last Run Time:                          2017-05-14 오후 4:39:07
Last Result:                            0
Author:                                 lg\Administrator
Task To Run:                        C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\Test\Powershell\dns.ps1
Start In:                               N/A
Comment:                                N/A
Scheduled Task State:                   Enabled
Idle Time:                              Disabled
Power Management:                       Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries
Run As User:                            LG\administrator
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:         Disabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins:   72:00:00
Schedule:                               Scheduling data is not available in this format.
Schedule Type:                          When an event occurs
Start Time:                             N/A
Start Date:                             N/A
End Date:                               N/A
Days:                                   N/A
Months:                                 N/A
Repeat: Every:                          N/A
Repeat: Until: Time:                    N/A
Repeat: Until: Duration:                N/A
Repeat: Stop If Still Running:          N/A
```

This is result.

[image]

But there are not log all dns request.

[image]

My script log last dns request only among dns request that occurred at the same time. Is it the limit of the task scheduler? How can i log all dns request?

[image]

And when run code of restless1987, it is occured error below.

```
Register-WMIEvent : Wrong Class. 
Location D:\test.ps1:9 Character:1
+ Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent within 3 $filter ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Register-WmiEvent], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.ManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterWmiEventCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Taskscheduler can be quite unreliable in certain circumstances.

If this happens to be in your case, maybe you can go along with registering a powershell wmi event watcher, to log every instance that gets created there.

There is still something to do, but it should be a place to start. You have to adapt the filter, that it gets the events from the correct logfile.

```
$class = 'Win32_NtEventLog'
$EventCode = 3006
$filter = "Where TargetInstance ISA '$class' and eventcode = '$EventCode'"

$codeblock = {
    $eventargs.newevent.targetinstance #<- should have all info you need
}

Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent within 3 $filter" `
-messageData "DNS event " -sourceIdentifier "New DNS query" -Action $codeblock

While ($true){
    Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am new to powershell. So your answer is difficult to me. I need to study more.:)